# Impossible to set AWSAPIGatewayClient configuration in Swift 3?

Tags: swift, amazon-web-services, swift3, aws-api-gateway

I'm trying to add a generated AWS API Gateway SDK to my iOS app written in Swift 3. The code generated by AWS contains a lot of things that don't compile in Swift 3, but hopefully I can work around most of them. One of the errors has gotten me really confused though.

The (precompiled) AWSAPIGatewayClient class from the AWS library looks like this:

```
open class AWSAPIGatewayClient : NSObject {   
    open var configuration: AWSServiceConfiguration! { get }
    open var apiKey: String!
}
```

And the generated child class has this init function:

```
init(configuration: AWSServiceConfiguration) {
    super.init()

    self.configuration = configuration

    ...
}
```

The compiler naturally complains that the configuration property is get-only:

```
AWSMyServiceClient.swift:127:25: Cannot assign to property: 'configuration' is a get-only property
```

Am I missing something obvious, or how could this possibly work? I haven't been able to find anybody else with the same issue, which leads me to suspect there's something wrong with my particular code.

Comment: I have always used the AWS API Gateway obj-c generated code in a Swift 2.2  project. I've converted my project to Swift 3 and it works well (still with obj-c generated code). I just noticed today that they provide Swift code. I tried to replace the obj-c code with the generated Swift, but, as you said, it has a lot of compile errors. No way I'm going to fix compile errors in generated code. This should work out-of-the-box. I can not find any documentation about the generated Swift, when it was introduced, for which version, and how to use it. For now I will stick with the obj-c.

Comment: Thank you, this was very helpful input. I'll try this approach next, as much of the advantages of auto generating code is lost if you have to make changes to it every time you update it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The API Gateway generated SDK for Swift also provides with a file named `AWSApiGatewayBridge.h` in the package which is imported via the bridging header of your app(showed in `Bridging_Header.h`).

The Generated SDK won't work without `AWSApiGatewayBridge.h` imported in your project via the objective c bridging header.

Thanks, 
Rohan

Comment: I have included `AWSApiGatewayBridge.h` in my bridging header file, but something like that would explain a lot of things that feel off with the generated client. Another example is the line `private static var token: dispatch_once_t = 0` in the generated client, according to the compiler `dispatch_once_t` isn't available in Swift. Is this just a Swift 3 thing, or could it be a clue as to why the generated code doesn't compile?

Comment: It would be a Swift 3 thing. The generated SDK works correctly with Swift 2.3. But the issues related to configuration object being only readable should be solved with the bridging header. You could take an alternative approach to address the dispatch_once_t issue and your SDK should be working fine.

Comment: I removed and added the bridging header file from my build settings, cleaned and built the project, still without success. Then as I was hopelessly tinkering with the code, the build errors started to disappear from the left panel. A few remained, but the configuration issue went away! I don't know why the change wasn't immediate, but I'm very happy you were right. Thanks!